# Unable to upload Image with Retrofit 2

Tags: android, laravel, retrofit2, image-uploading

I am unable to upload an image from Retrofit 2, please look at my below code

```
@Multipart
@POST("upload-image")
Call<UploadImageResponse> uploadFile(@Part MultipartBody.Part file, @Part("file") RequestBody name);
```

and the function i call performs like that,

```
// Uploading Image
public void uploadFile()
{
    // Map is used to multipart the file using okhttp3.RequestBody
    File file = new File(sellerActivity.mediaPath);

    // Parsing any Media type file
    RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), file);

    MultipartBody.Part fileToUpload = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("file", file.getName(), requestBody);

    RequestBody filename = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), file.getName());

    Call<UploadImageResponse> call = apiService.uploadFile(fileToUpload, filename);

    call.enqueue(new Callback<UploadImageResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<UploadImageResponse> call, Response<UploadImageResponse> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful())
            {
                System.out.println("Image Url: " + response.body().getImage() + " " + response.body().getDishesName());
                System.out.println("Image Message: " + response.raw());
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Image Message: " + response.raw());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<UploadImageResponse> call, Throwable t) {
            System.out.println("onFailure: " + t);
        }
    });
}
```

when I use postman I do that

[image: Postman Screenshot]

I have searched and tried various methods but no success. any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I do't see you using `image` as a key for your file part in Android.

Comment: please see update!

Comment: check what does the `response.body().` contain.

Comment: response.body() returns packagename.UploadImageResponse@1f18fc0

Comment: that is wrong. Check it's fields. What you showd is just a default `toString(0` implementation of `Object`

Comment: also show the `UploadImageResponse` class

Comment: Can you Please Show me UploadImageResponse Class that you use @MaK

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must have a clear understanding of multipart form data, so read [this link](http://derpturkey.com/node-multipart-form-data-explained/) and many others available out there.

Answer is Change your endpoint method as given below:

```
@Multipart
@POST("upload-image")
Call<UploadImageResponse> uploadFile(@Part MultipartBody.Part file, @Part("dishes_name") RequestBody name);
```

You are missing to assign proper keys to each part.

Also, change the implementation as below:

```
// Uploading Image
public void uploadFile()
{
    // Map is used to multipart the file using okhttp3.RequestBody
    File file = new File(sellerActivity.mediaPath);

    // Parsing any Media type file
    RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), file);

    MultipartBody.Part fileToUpload = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("image", file.getName(), requestBody);

    RequestBody filename = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), file.getName());

    Call<UploadImageResponse> call = apiService.uploadFile(fileToUpload, filename);

    call.enqueue(new Callback<UploadImageResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<UploadImageResponse> call, Response<UploadImageResponse> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful())
            {
                System.out.println("Image Url: " + response.body().getImage() + " " + response.body().getDishesName());
                System.out.println("Image Message: " + response.raw());
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Image Message: " + response.raw());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<UploadImageResponse> call, Throwable t) {
            System.out.println("onFailure: " + t);
        }
    });
}
```

The first parameter in the `MultipartBody.Part.createFormData(keyName, fileName, requestBody)` method is the key name of the multipart file, the second parameter is the filename, the third parameter is the request body of this part. [link](https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/MultipartBody.Part.html).

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you so much, it works only one thing is not working was @Part("image") so i removed "image" like @Part MultipartBody.Part file and now its working fine. thanks once again

Comment: i tried to upvote but it says Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.

Comment: **Payload Too Large**

Comment: Not helping In my case Postman return a desire response but retrofit return 500.